# Gcc error: 'NULL' and 'stderr' undeclared

Tags: gcc

I'm using gcc 4.6.0 for armv7. Today I needed to compile this source:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int main(void)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(".");
    if(dir)
    {
        struct dirent *ent;
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            puts(ent->d_name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening directory\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At compilation there were here such errors:

> test.c: In function 'main': test.c:10:31: error: 'NULL' undeclared
>   (first use in this function) test.c:10:31: note: each undeclared
>   identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   test.c:17:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in
>   function 'fprintf' [enabled by default] test.c:17:9: error: 'stderr'
>   undeclared (first use in this function)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following include:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have something set